# I can't move navbar logo to the left

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, alignment, navbar

I am trying to simply move the logo to the left a bit, all attempts at doing so have failed.

At first, I figured maybe it was because I have wrapped in the `.main_nav_container` or the `container` and a `<div col-lg-12>` but rearranging it has done nothing but ruined the layout.

I want to nudge the logo over to the left. I have used the debug tools to highlight the space (see photos) I have to work with. I also understand that the `col-lg-12` is what's keeping everything in line with the rest of the page content. What am I doing wrong?

The HTML is wrapped in a PHP file and this is a purchased template if any of that matters.

I have tried adjusting the positioning with `class = float-left` in the img line or text `align-left` but to no avail. I have also tried adjusting it with css script also to no avail. I have not attached a css file since none worked. 
See images for more info.

```html
<div class="main_nav_container">
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                     <nav class="navbar">
                          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                             <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x90" 
                               width=300 height=90>
                            </a>
                            <ul class= "navbar_menu">
                               <li>home</li> 
                               <li>shop</li>
                               <li>blog</li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                  </div>
             </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Moving the logo to the left is all I need to do.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwRZ9W0OiYxibkkxRUhKUzhhZTVtYnk1TTZkbmIxRWtVMWV3

Comment: I can't understand if you want to move the logo to the right or to the left... Also, your images aren't visible, please add them in a correct way using `img` button while in [edit] mode of your question.

Comment: When sharing a file in Google Drive you have to be sure that it's accessible for everyone.. The rights aren't alright..

Comment: But, besides the problems with your questions, I think that what you want is a CSS: `.navbar-brand > img {float: right}`

Comment: I assume what you want is to display image and bullet points side by side. If it is so, you may include 'float: left' to both classes 'navbar-brand' and 'navbar_menu'.

Comment: @CalvinNunes it should be visible now, move it to the left, the image shows you exactly what I want to do.

Comment: if it has to be moved to left, why in the title you say "right" and in the first paragraph you say "right" again?
have you tried `.navbar-brand > img {float: left}` ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes my apologies I didn't even notice that was the title, I  corrected the title. my apologies, I will try out your recommendation.

Comment: @CalvinNunes this worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `container` class to a `container-fluid`. The container class will squish your navbar like in your picture, giving you limited room to work with. After that, you will be able to position your other elements correctly.

Comment: Imm give this a shot